# RoR iOS Push Notifications with Grocer Gem

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, rubymotion

I'm very new to RoR and web servers in general. Basically I want to create a web service to run push notifications for my iOS app.

I'm trying to use the [Grocer Gem](https://github.com/grocer/grocer) and so far i can get it working if i put the functions in the rakefile in my RoR project... but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

The two functions I'm using are [Connecting](https://github.com/grocer/grocer#connecting) and [Sending Notifications](https://github.com/grocer/grocer#sending-notifications)

1) Where *should* I put those functions.

2) How do I make those functions run when the server starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files in the config/initializers folder are auto-loaded when the app starts. You can put all the *Connecting* section's codes in there. You should change `pusher` to a global variable so it's accessible outside the file:

```
$pusher = Grocer.pusher(...)
# instead of:
# pusher = Grocer.pusher(...)
```

The code in the *Sending Notifications* code can be called anywhere. Just make sure you use the global variable when you call `$pusher.push(notification)`.

By the way, the Rakefile is used for 'tasks' which are not meant to be called
in your app. For example, commands you call manually in your shell like
`rake db:migrate` and `rake assets:precompile`. So unless you're making one of these,
there's no reason to edit that file.